# including header file

Tags: c, header

I have some question about header files(I'm talking about c, but I think it will be the same for c++), let's assume I have some `my_ADT.c` file (inside I have implementation of the functions and actual `struct`) and also `my_ADT.h` inside I have `pointer for my struct`
`Question:` if I use ADT `Set` for implementation `my_ADT` do I need to include `set.h` to both files `my_ADT.h and my_ADT.c` or including only to `my_ADT.h` will be sufficient (inside my_ADT.c I have `#include "my_ADT.h"`) thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `my_ADT.h` is included in the `my_ADT.c` file, then you should include `set.h` only in `my_ADT.h`.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 scenarios

1. `set.h` is needed ONLY in `my_ADT.h`
2. `set.h` is needed ONLY in `my_ADT.c`
3. `set.h` is needed in both `my_ADT.h` and `my_ADT.c`
4. *`set.h` is not needed at all :-)*

For scenario 3) add the `#include "set.h"` to the file `my_ADT.h`, **document that fact**, and `#include "my_ADT.h"` in `my_ADT.c` (with proper include guards, you lose nothing by including `set.h` also to the C file).

For scenario 2) include `set.h` only in `my_ADT.c`

For scenario 1) include `set.h` only in `my_ADT.h`

Answer (score 0):

In addiction to pmg answer you must know that a good way of avoiding #include problem is to surround all header file with a precomplier instruction that check if the .h file has been already included.

```
#ifndef __my_ADT_header
#define __my_ADT_header
/*
 * your header declaration here
 */
#endif
```

this prevent error caused by multiple header inclusion

hope this helps